# Programmatically re import subreport in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a header subreport who is used in a lot of reports. (about 40-50 reports)

I want the header to be up to date without doing anything manually each time.

Do you know how it can be done ?

By the way, my crystal reports version is 10.5 (The default one in VS2008)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the subreport is implemented, you may have some options.  Subreports can be made either completely embedded in the parent report OR imported on opening of the parent file.

For example, open up a few of your parent reports and right-click on the subreport.  Go into the sub-report's properties menu.  If you see a **re-import when opening** option, then it's not embedded.

I'm not sure what your question is, exactly.  If you are designing these reports and want to make a sort of Master/Template SubReport, then you should make it independently, import it into each report, and check the option to automatically re-import the subreport every time the main report is accessed.  This way, you only have to update the 1 Master/Template SubReport and all the Parent Reports will be auto-updated next time they're opened.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your reports to automatically update the SubReport when it is changed, there are two options in Crystal Reports 2020:

### 1. Specific for each SubReport

In each template, you change the option for the SubReport so that it is "automatically imported". This has also been described by @PowerUser

1. click *Format Subreport* in the Format menu.
2. click the *Subreport* tab in the Format Editor dialogue box.
3. Click *Re-import When Opening*.

Now the **current Subreport is updated** when the main report is opened and updated.

### 2. Globally import each SubReport automatically when opened

Change the options for CrystalReports so it's done automatically for every SubReport.

1. On the File menu, click Options.
2. In the Options dialog box, click the Reporting tab.
3. Click Re-import Subreport on Open.
4. Click OK.

Now **EVERY subreport will be updated** when its main report is opened

---

We use the second option because we have less maintenance.

Source: [SAP Crystal Reports 2020 User Guide](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_CRYSTAL_REPORTS/dfc124becfa845ffa91b1e717b20e3ec/049eabcdac2d4a9991f632d1d93a2e7c.html?locale=en-US)